# how to specify search_filter='(objectClass=group)',search_scope='SUBTREE',attributes = ['member']) for django python3 ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap, ldap-query

I am using django python3 ldap package to sync some users from ldap server to my django application.
Its getting connected to ldap server with my configurations defined in settings but user lookup is failed.
The search base that i am using is

```
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "CN=SOME_USERS,OU=Security Group,OU=Example,DC=Example,DC=com"
```

But I get my result with a different package named ldap3.

for ldap3 I can specify some extra parameters along with search_base like below

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, SAFE_SYNC
server = Server('my_server')
conn = Connection(server, 'my_user', 'my_password', client_strategy=SAFE_SYNC, 
auto_bind=True)
conn.search(search_base='CN=DTS_USERS,OU=Security 
Group,OU=Viacom18,DC=viacom18,DC=com',search_filter='(objectClass=group)'
        ,attributes = ['member'])
```

I just want to know how can I specify "search_filter='(objectClass=group)'
,attributes = ['member']" with django python3 ldap. I checked the documentation at https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap but could not find any helpful thing.

Here are the all my settings

```
    LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldaps://example.com:636"

LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = True

LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE = "CN=SOME_USERS,OU=Security Group,OU=Example,DC=Example,DC=com"

LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS = "group"
LDAP_AUTH_USER_LOOKUP_FIELDS = ("username",)
LDAP_AUTH_CLEAN_USER_DATA = "django_python3_ldap.utils.clean_user_data"
LDAP_AUTH_SYNC_USER_RELATIONS = "django_python3_ldap.utils.sync_user_relations"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS = "utils.ftp.custom_format_search_filters"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory_principal"
LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = "example.com"
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_USERNAME = "my_user"
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECTION_PASSWORD = "password"
LDAP_AUTH_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = None
LDAP_AUTH_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = None

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_python3_ldap.auth.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',  # this is default
    'guardian.backends.ObjectPermissionBackend',  # guardian dependencies
)
```

My functions is

```
def custom_format_search_filters(ldap_fields):
search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
search_filters.append("(memberOf=CN=SOME_USERS,OU=Security Group,OU=Example,DC=Example,DC=com)")
return search_filters
```

I just wanna sync the users inside the SOME_USERS group
Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

Those two packages are for different purposes. The `ldap3` package is a general-purpose LDAP library. The `django-python3-ldap` package is to "Authenticate users with an LDAP server".

Your `ldap3` code looks like it is looking for members of a specific group. If your goal is to only allow users of that group to authenticate, then the documentation does touch on that under the [Custom User Filters](https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap#custom-user-filters) heading. Notice this:

```
# Advanced: apply custom LDAP filter logic.
search_filters.append("(|(memberOf=groupA)(memberOf=GroupB))")
```

That would limit authentication to only users in `groupA` or `GroupB`.

Comment: Yes I have created same with filter this search_filters.append("(|(memberOf=cn=DTS_USERS))")    my group name is DTS_USERS. but it does not sync users from this group but only print connect succeed. any idea whats wrong I am doing? Well I appreciate your answer.

Comment: You need to use the full distinguished name, and since you only have one group, you don't need the OR (`|`). So something like this: `search_filters.append("(memberOf=CN=DTS_USERS,OU=Security 
Group,OU=Viacom18,DC=viacom18,DC=com)")`

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I appreciate your answer and tried with that. but again it shows "LDAP connect succeeded" but does not sync the users. Now I have added my settings conf to the question can you please give it a look. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Do you have this line that's in the documentation? `from django_python3_ldap.utils import format_search_filters` Also, is the body of your `custom_format_search_filters` function indented properly? Or was that just a copy/paste error?

Comment: I may not be much more help. I know LDAP, but not python very well.

Comment: Yes I have imported format_search_filters and function is properly intended and it's executed without giving result